# OMShell Simulation Times Output

Tags: time, simulation, modelica, openmodelica

When I simulate an OpenModelica model using OMShell I got the following times as output:

```
timeFrontend 
timeBackend 
timeSimCode 
timeTemplates 
timeCompile 
timeSimulation 
timeTotal
```

I wasn't able to find any information about the meaning of each of them. Do you know the meaning of each of these times? Do you know some documentation that can help me figure this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here it goes from the top of my head:

- timeFrontend: the time it takes to flatten the Modelica code (remove structure and expand connects, etc) to get to a hybrid DAE
- timeBackend: the time it takes to do a lot of symbolic manipulations to the system to bring it to ODE form (causalization, blt transformation, index reduction, matching, etc)
- timeSimCode: time to generate the structures for code generation
- timeTemplates: the time it takes to generate the C or C++ files from SimCode stuctures
- timeCompile: the time it takes to compile the generated C or C++ files via gcc or clang into a simulation executable
- timeSimulation: the time it takes to run the generated simulation executable to get the simulation results
- timeTotal: duh :)